# How to concatenate multiple columns of Strings vertically?

Tags: java

I have the following Strings:

```
String a = "ABC";
String b = "BCD";
String c = "CDE";
...
```

Could someone tell me how can I achieve something like that?

```
String result = "
A, B, C\n
B, C, D\n
C, D, E\n
";
```

I tried it with different ways but none is universal and error-free.

One example:

```
String a = "ABC";
String b = "BCD";
String c = "CDE";
String result = "";
int length = 3;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += a.substring(i, i+1);
    result += ", ";
    result += b.substring(i, i+1);
    result += ", ";
    result += c.substring(i, i+1);
    result += "\n";
}
```

It works but it is ugly because I don't really know how much "columns" I have. I mean it can be only a,b,c or more d,e,f,g,h... Also length of that strings can be different, 3 is only an example.

Comment: "_I tried it with different ways_" - Please show your attempt and describe where you got stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by "universal" or "error free"?

Comment: "universal" and "error-free" I mean I don't really know how many variables I got. It can be a,b,c just like above or more. I have that variables on list.

Comment: you should give a better example, since in yours columns and rows are interchangable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello this code works well;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "ABC";
    String b = "BCD";
    String c = "CDE";
    String result = "";
    
    result = parseSpecialString(a, b, c);
    
    System.out.println(result);
}

/**
 * @param strArr is any size str arguments
 * @return example : A, B, C
    B, C, D
    C, D, E
 */
static String parseSpecialString(String ...strArr){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    String NEW_LINE = "\n";

    for (String str : strArr) {
        sb.append(convertCsvStr(str)).append(NEW_LINE);
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}

//convert ABC -> A, B, C
static String convertCsvStr(String str){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    final String COMMA = ", ";
    
    String[] strArr = str.split("");
    
    //strArr is {"", "A", "B", "C"}, so start index 1
    for (int i = 1; i< strArr.length ; i++) {
        
        sb.append(strArr[i]);
        
        //add comma until last item
        if(i != strArr.length -1){
            sb.append(COMMA);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString() ;
}
```

Comment: Only works well with quadratic problems, means array size == string length

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "ABC";
    String b = "BCD";
    String c = "CDE";

    String result = Stream.of(a, b, c)
        .map(s -> String.join(", ", s.split("")) + "\n")
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

output:

```
A, B, C
B, C, D
C, D, E
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 15, there are text blocks:

```
String example = """
    Hello,
        world.
""";
```

But before that release, you're stuck with concatenation in some form. The good news is the compiler will take care of joining together literals and constants for you:

```
String result = "A, B, C\n"
              + "B, C, D\n"
              + "C, D, E\n";
```

Comment: Please look up for updated post.

Comment: With the update in mind, think of it in terms of having an array of strings (instead of variables `a`, `b`, and `c`). With this, you should be able to iterate over the strings in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pre-define the arbitrary number of **strings** in a class,

```java
class MyClass {
    String a = "ABC";
    String b = "BCD";
    String c = "CDE";
}
```

then you can retrieve all the class variables and traverse them with reflection as follows:

```java
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

Field[] fields = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    System.out.println(String.join(", ", field.get(myClass).toString().split("")));
}
```

Console output:

> A, B, C
> B, C, D
> C, D, E

---

For more information reflection, please refer to [Guide to Java Reflection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection).

Answer (score 0):

`String::replaceAll` may be used to add a comma with a space after each letter/digit except for the last character.

Then the strings can be joined using `Collectors.joining("\n")`.

```java
String a = "ABC", b = "CDE", c = "EFG";

String result = Stream.of(a, b, c)
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("(\\w)(?!$)", "$1, "))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
A, B, C
C, D, E
E, F, G
```

Theres's no need to split each string into lots of substrings in this task.